# Interface genérica como tipo de retorno?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo una pregunta que seguro que es muy básica. Lo que no entiendo es para que se utiliza una interfaz como tipo de retorno. Sigue siendo un tipo de la misma manera? Que utilidad tiene?

```
public interface ISessions {
   <IEnumerable<User>> RetrieveUser(string userId);
}

IEnumerable<User> = RetrieveUser(x);
```

Comment: Las interfaces són un contrato que dice básicamente qué funciones, métodos, variables va a TENER que inicializar o implementer una clase que lo **herede**. No hay implementaciones. Es información :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como menciona [Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16417/4499): *Al definir una interfaz de retorno te da libertad en variar el tipo de dato concreto que devuelves sin afectar a quien invoca la funcionalidad.*

A modo de adición, te voy a dar un ejemplo, considera que tienes la siguiente interfaz:

```
public interface IVehiculo
{
    string ObtenerPlaca();
}
```

La interfaz por si sola no hace gran cosa, no? Por lo que debemos crear componentes *(Llamados `vehiculos`)* para que su funcionamiento tenga sentido:

```
public class Carro : IVehiculo
{
    private string _Placa;
    public Carro(string placa) { _Placa = placa; }
    public string ObtenerPlaca() { return this._Placa; }
}
```

¡Bien!, tenemos nuestra clase `Carro` que resuelve el comportamiento de la interfaz `IVehiculo`, pero... ¿Qué tal si queremos hacer una que otra implementación?

```
public class Motor : IVehiculo
{
    private string _Placa;
    private string _Modelo;
    public Motor(string placa, string modelo) { _Placa = placa; _Modelo = modelo; }
    public string ObtenerPlaca() { return this._Placa; }
    public string ObtenerModelo() { return this._Modelo; }
}
```

¡Oh! Tenemos dos clases con la misma interfaz ¿Y una está *más desarrollada que otra*?

Pues, ambas heredan de `IVehiculo`, puedes probar el siguiente código en cualquier lugar y te funcionará de forma que todos los elementos que comparten la interfaz pueden compartir el comportamiento:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    // Definimos una que otra lista para hacerla "nuestra base de datos"
    public static List<IVehiculo> Vehiculos = new List<IVehiculo>()
    {
        new Carro("123-123-12"),
        new Motor("321-32-321", "Alguna marca"),
        new Motor("22-223-210", "Otra marca"),
        new Carro("222-3-23-2")
    };

    // Definición de la  función para obtener un motor.
    public static IVehiculo ObtenerMotorPorPlaca(string placa)
    {
        foreach (IVehiculo vh in Vehiculos)
        {
            if (vh.GetType() == typeof(Motor))
                if (vh.ObtenerPlaca() == placa) return vh;
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Inicio:
    public static void Main()
    {
        IVehiculo MiVehiculo = new Motor("21132", "wwq"); // Puedo definir un motor
        Console.WriteLine("Placa del motor: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca() + " Modelo: " + ((Motor)MiVehiculo).ObtenerModelo());

        // Asi como puedo definir un carro:
        MiVehiculo = new Carro("23232");
        Console.WriteLine("Placa del motor: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca());

        MiVehiculo = ObtenerMotorPorPlaca("321-32-321");
        Console.WriteLine("Placa del vehiculo buscado: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca()); 
    }
}
```

Si bien no es el ejemplo más practico, pero sirve para demostrar como funcionan las interfaces.

Las interfaces son algo así como un sello que se le aplica a una clase para marcar su *"Comportamiento"*, dicho de manera "alocada". Una clase que implementa una interfaz, debe llevar todos los elementos de esa interfaz para desarrollar su comportamiento.

#### EDIT: Para aclarar algo.

Elementos con la misma interfaz implementada, tienen básicamente el mismo comportamiento, pero esto no quiere decir que sean iguales, en el ejemplo anterior he puesto una interfaz `IVehiculo` y otras dos clases `Motor` y `Carro`, lo he puesto por la siguiente razón:

La siguiente función devuelve un `Carro` o un `Motor` dependiendo su placa.

```
public static IVehiculo ObtenerMotorPorPlaca(string placa)
{
    foreach (IVehiculo vh in Vehiculos)
    {
        if (vh.ObtenerPlaca() == placa) return vh;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Y modificamos el código del método `Main()` anterior y agregamos:

```
public static void Main()
{
    IVehiculo MiVehiculo = new Motor("21132", "wwq"); // Puedo definir un motor
    Console.WriteLine("Placa del motor: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca() + " Modelo: " + ((Motor)MiVehiculo).ObtenerModelo());

    // Asi como puedo definir un carro:
    MiVehiculo = new Carro("23232");
    Console.WriteLine("Placa del motor: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca());
    Console.WriteLine(MiVehiculo.GetType()); // Carro.      

    MiVehiculo = ObtenerMotorPorPlaca("321-32-321");
    Console.WriteLine("Placa del vehiculo buscado: " + MiVehiculo.ObtenerPlaca()); 
    Console.WriteLine(MiVehiculo.GetType()); // Motor,
}
```

He agregado 2 `GetType()` para confirmar el tipo de dato usado en ambas asignaciones, la razón por la que nunca se devuelve el tipo de la interfaz, sino el tipo de clase que "firma" un contrato al implementar esa interfaz para adoptar ese comportamiento, sin embargo, pude retornar distintos tipos de una misma funcion, siempre que implementan la misma interfaz.

---

Algunos enlaces de referencia: [Interfaces](http://geeks.ms/etomas/2010/07/07/c-bsico-interfaces/), [MSDN (ingles)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx), [Uno que otro fiddle... (actualizado)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/idoT1n).

Comment: Pero cuando retorna una interfície genérica con la classe User, ya esta retornando el tipo(IEnumerable<User> = RetrieveUser(x);)pero solo le permite visualizar los métodos de IEnumerable? El concepto de interfaz lo entiendo lo que me cuesta de entender es el retorno de la interfaz con la clase.

Comment: Si usas la interfaz como tipo de retorno, estas supuesto a poder devolver mas de un tipo que implemente `IEnumerable`. Como es el caso de las colecciones en en .NET, si tienes una función que devuelve `IEnumerable<T>`, esta puede devolver un `List<T>`, cualquier cosa que implemente esa interfaz. Solo se vuelve genérico el valor que puede retornar.

Comment: Pero a todo esto que diferencia habría en si carro y moto heredaran de una clase base por ejemplo Vehiculo. Evidentemente ObtenerMotorPorPlaca() tendría que retornar el tipo de la clase base. Simplemente el comportamiento seria el exactamente el mismo?

Comment: @gvivetapplus Mira el editado.

Answer (score 2):

Al definir una interfaz de retorno te da libertad en variar el tipo de dato concreto que devuelves sin afectar a quien invoca la funcionalidad

Recuerda que clases como ser [List<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.100).aspx), la implementan por eso podrias devolverla como respuesta, pero no es la unica

[El enumerador genérico IEnumerable. Fundamentos de LINQ II](http://www.genbetadev.com/cnet/el-enumerador-generico-ienumerable-fundamentos-de-linq-ii)

Tambien tiene relacion con linq, ya que podrias generar una query y devolver el resultado directamente ya que IQueryable<> tambien la implementa.

Comment: Entonces devolver List<T> e IList<t> que diferencias supone?

Answer (score 1):

Una interfaz es útil en varios escenarios, por ejemplo, cuando necesitas enviar una notificación a un usuario. El comportamiento debe recibir dos argumentos, el mensaje y el usuario. Sin embargo hasta este punto lo que hemos hecho es definir el comportamiento. Ese comportamiento es el que definiríamos en una interfaz (ISender), de tal manera que nuestra función (Main) no sea necesario que conozca quién y cómo la implementa.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISender sender = new MailSender();
        sender.Send(1, "¡Hola mundo!");
    }
}

class MailSender : ISender
{
    public void Send(int userId, string mensaje)
    {
        // Aquí abriría una conexión SMTP y enviaría el correo.
    }
}

interface ISender
{
    void Send(int userId, string mensaje);
}
```

Lo útil en estos casos, es que si por ejemplo necesitamos cambiar la implementación, simplemente creamos una nueva clase que implemente dicha interfaz.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISender sender = new FileSender();
        sender.Send(1, "¡Hola mundo!");
    }
}

class FileSender : ISender
{
    public void Send(int userId, string mensaje)
    {
        // No envio el correo, solo lo guardo 
        // en un archivo
    }
}
```

De tal manera que conocemos el comportamiento, más no la implementación, y si lo aplicamos como preguntas, entonces podemos tener una función que se encargue de definir que clase será la que realizará el trabajo.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Obtenemos la clase que se encargará de realizar el trabajo.
        ISender sender = GetSender();
        sender.Send(1, "¡Hola mundo!");
    }

    static ISender GetSender()
    {
        // Podríamos haber usado FileSender o MailSender
        // Ambos implementan ISender.
        return new MailSender();
    }
}
```

Este es un sólo ejemplo adicional a los que ya te mencionaron, espero que te ayude a comprender el uso de interfaces.

Cuando usas [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) para la [inyección de dependencias](http://blog.agilistic.nl/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependancy-injection-in-c-sharp/) disfrutas de trabajar con interfaces.

Saludos.