# Definición de interfaz

Tags: poo

Hay algo que no me queda claro conceptualmente. Cuándo se hace referencia al término interfaz ¿a qué se refiere exactamente?

He visto que se pueden referir a esto como a los métodos de una clase o a una clase puramente abstracta que solo contienen métodos sin su implementación.

Comment: Relacionado: [Interface genérica como tipo de retorno?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/16420/127)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En teoría de programación orientada a objetos, donde todo es un objeto y los objetos se comunican entre sí a través de mensajes.

La interfaz son los mensajes que sabe responder un objeto (también se lo conoce como protocolo).

En un lenguaje orientado a objetos puro basado en clases, la interfaz está dada por la/s clase/s a las que pertenece el objeto.

En un  lenguaje orientado a objetos puro basado en prototipos, no queda otra que analizar el objeto en sí para saber que mensajes acepta.

En lenguajes como Java o C#, las construcciones del tipo Interface, siguen está idea, es decir definen que métodos (mensajes) debe responder una clase que la implementen (la interfaz) y son un mecanismo para tratar con la herencia multiple.

Para ejemplos de interfaz mira la respuesta de `fredyfx`.

Referencia: [Notas de Alan Kay sobre la definición de orientado a objetos](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AlanKaysDefinitionOfObjectOriented).

Alan Kay es el padre de Smalltalk, considerado el primer lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos.

Comment: ¡Gracias!, Ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor.

Answer (score 6):

Entendamos este concepto con un ejemplo de la vida real:

**Medios de transporte**: auto, avion, barco: Los 3 aceleran, frenan, tienen un control de dirección (manubrio/volante), pero la manera en que lo hacen es diferente. Aqui se define una interfaz con los 3 elementos mencionados cuya implementación es diferente.

Un interface es un "**contrato de implementación**" entre clases, donde se agrupan las clases por lo "**que hacen**", a diferencia de la herencia que agrupa las clases por "lo que son".

Comment: Buena idea, pero me parece que habría que pulir un poco los ejemplos. Me parece que describen mejor el concepto de encapsulamiento.

Comment: Ej, en un auto (o vehículo terrestre) esperas encontrar un acelerador, un freno y un control de dirección (manubrio, volante).

Comment: buen aporte, vamos puliendo :D

Answer (score 4):

Al menos en el caso de C# una interface no es mas que un contrato compuesto por métodos y propiedades declarado con la palabra clave interface, todas aquellas clases que implementan la interface deben obligatoriamente cumplimentar los métodos expuestos en ella.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/87d83y5b.aspx

Comment: Esa es una de las definiciones pero es concepto en si es algo abstracto o relativo ¿no? por que a interfaz también se puede referir: _conjunto de subrutinas, funciones y procedimientos (o métodos, en la programación orientada a objetos) que ofrece cierta biblioteca para ser utilizado por otro software como una capa de abstracción._

Comment: Yo creo que un conjunto de subrutinas, funciones y procedimientos que ofrece una biblioteca mas bien es un API 

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interfaz_de_programaci%C3%B3n_de_aplicaciones

Un API es un conjunto de funciones, procedimientos, subrutinas para acceder a los componentes de una librería, control o servicio, pero no creo que tenga que ver con la POO mas bien es algo general de la programación en componentes.

Comment: Eso es a lo que me refiero, es decir a las dos se le denominan como interfaz, pero no tienen cada que ver. Es decir en una API consumes un servicio que encapsula cierta información y la interfaz o interface es una clase puramente abstracta  para definir después una determinada función ¿no?

Comment: Si, al menos yo lo entiendo como dos cosas diferentes, yo a la exposición de métodos de una librería lo conozco mas como API, pero esta claro que la denominación interface tambien le sirve.

Comment: No es exclusivo de C#, en Java se acepta también esta definición. Incluso diría que es mas que agnóstica al lenguaje el hecho de que se convierta en un contrato con el cliente que la implementa.